# how to convert 420 10 bit LE planar format (I420_10LE) to 422 10 bit LE packed (UYVP)

Tags: gstreamer, yuv

I have captured I420_10LE and UYVP outputs from gstreamer, and I am trying to understand how does gstreamer packs the y, u, v samples from the I420_10LE in the UYVP format.

I can trace how the bits from the I420_10LE are packed in the UYVP. But the values of the y samples are baffling. They seem to be off by 1 from the original values.

Are there any color matrix conversion involved that might explain this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to call videoconvert like this:
... ! videconvert dither=0 chroma-mode=3 ... !

Once I did this, the output conformed to what I was expecting.